# Show a Modal Window on Form Submit and Submit form While Modal "Accept" Button is clicked?

Tags: jquery, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form with Validations already in place, When i submit the form I have shown bootstrap Modal Window, Know The modal window has two buttons accept and cancel, On click of Accept button i want form to be submit and on cancel close the modal.

```
var errorMessages = [];

    $("#f").submit(function(event){

         $("input,select,textarea").not("[type=submit]").each(function (i, el) {
           errorMessages = errorMessages.concat(
               $(this).triggerHandler("validation.validation")
           );
         });     
    if(errorMessages.length==0){     
    $('#myModal').modal("show");
    $("#agreesubmit").on('click',function(){
        $("#myModal").modal("hide");
       return true;  
      });
    }
    event.preventDefault();
    });
```

Now i am stuck at the click of #agreesubmit button when i click it, i want the form to submit and not sure what to do here.

Comment: The form does not submits when i click on the agreesubmit button, I open "terms and conditions" modal on submit of form, On that modal i have #agreesubmit button, when i click on that button i want form to finally submit thats not happening.

Comment: do you have a live link to it? or a fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help? basically you need a "flag" to say the agreement was made, and then submit the form. I've shown a data-attribute being used as it's neat and simple.
I've not tested this code but it's logically sound.

```
$('#f').on('submit', function(e) {
  if( $(this).data('form-agree') !== true ) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // fire modal logic here.
  }
});

$('#agreesubmit').on('click', function() {
  $('#f').data('form-agree', true).submit();
});
```